# why do people say "get to a model" instead of "get a model"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

I am learning this [post](https://sweetcode.io/simple-multiple-linear-regression-python-scikit/).

The author says

> By using a model with three variables instead of one, we **get to a model** with a mean squared error of 19.12 and an R² score of 0.72.
>   That’s definitely a nice improvement!

"to" could be used as preposition, so "get to a model" seems to be grammatical.

why do people say "get to a model" instead of "get a model"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "to" emphasizes that a new model with a lower error and higher R² score was reached, a sort of accomplishment has occurred. The sentence works fine if the "to" was deleted, it slightly changes the meaning to mean "the result of the modification"

Answer (score 2):

Using to emphasises that this is a refinement of a previous model.

We have come *from* a model with one variable and we go *to* a model with three. It adds the sense that we have *reached* the improved model.

It would be possible to say "we get a model with three variables", and if the idea of "refining from a previous model" was not needed, this would be the normal way of saying it.

Answer (score 1):

*We get a model* uses a metaphor of "get" = "acquire", and says nothing about the circumstances of the acquisition.

*We get to a model* uses a different metaphor of "get to" = "reach, attain a destination", and implies that acquiring the model is the end-point of a journey.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Colin Fine, "get to" implies motion *towards* some goal, but the first clause doesn't provide any action; it assumes we are already *using* the model we are supposedly moving towards. I would write one of the following to be consistent:

- "By adding two variables to our model, we get to a model ..." That is, we started with a one-variable model, and the act of adding two variables moved us
  to a model with the new properties.
- "By using a model with three variables instead of one, we have a model with ..." That is, we don't dwell on "how" we arrived a three-variable model; we have one, and we state what its desirable properties are.